# Simultaneous interaction model with nonlinear equations

Tags: interaction, nonlinear

I observe many groups of 3 individuals, and I want to estimate an interaction model of the form:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
y_1&=f_1(x, y-1)+e_1\\
y_2&=f_2(x, y-2)+e_2\\
y_3&=f_3(x, y-3)+e_3
\end{array}$$

Where $x$ is an exogenous variable and $y-i$ represents the sum of LHS variables of partners, i.e. $y-1= (y_2+y_3)$. Importantly, the functional forms $f_1, \dots, f_3$ are non-linear in the parameters. Which is the preferable estimation method to recover the 3 associated parameters ($\beta_0$ for $x$, $\beta_1$ for $y-i$, and the variance of the error term)?

Many thanks,
M.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Note that questions about relevant packages in Stata, R, or whatever, are generally considered [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) per our FAQ. However, we welcome well-posed statistical issues, so perhaps you could emphasize the latter in your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I understand. I now mention the estimation method in the post above.